# Planning a Garden with Sparse Planting: Will Emerging Plants Fill in Gaps Over Time?

Tags: perennials, oudolf

I'm currently in the process of planning a garden, and I'm considering a more sparse planting arrangement. My concern is whether emerging plants, particularly those with spreading habits, will naturally fill in the gaps between them over time.

The selected plants for the garden include:

[image]

If I opt for a less dense planting arrangement initially, can I expect the emerging plants to naturally fill in the gaps, creating a denser appearance over time? Are there specific considerations or guidelines for choosing plants with spreading habits to achieve this effect? Any insights or experiences with similar garden designs would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you please transcribe the plant names you will use from the picture into text?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The design you're showing tells you how far apart to plant the major plants (Eupatorium, Molinia, for example) because it includes a scale. I have two suggestions for the smaller plants which are not specifically placed on the design, such as the Deschampsia:

1. If the plant is a groundcover, it will spread over time, so the distance apart you plant them will just determine how long it takes for the plants to fill in the area. The farther apart, the greater the number of growing seasons for full coverage.
2. If the plant is not a groundcover and if you want a "full" look at maturity, then determine the mature width and subtract 10-15% from it - that's the distance you'll want to plant them apart **on center**. For example, if the Deschampsia has a mature width of 30cm (not sure that this is correct-for illustrative purposes only), then the width you'll need for a full look may be closer to 26-27cm, which means that for any one plant, you should plant its neighbor 26 or 27cm from its center. This applies for neighboring plants of a different genus or cultivar as well (where they border each other).

Your garden will look sparse the first year and then gradually fill in; my experience is that it will start looking pretty good at the end of its third growing season, and "mature" at the end of its fifth season.

You asked "Are there specific considerations or guidelines for choosing plants with spreading habits to achieve this effect?" Just the basics in my opinion - match the plants to the site in terms of sun exposure, hardiness for your area, drought-tolerance (or not, depending on your irrigation, if any), drainage (if this is an issue for the site), and availability for purchase in your area.

If you cannot get a plant that's recommended in the design, then if you want to match the look of the design, I recommend trying to get a similar plant from the same genus and species, if possible. If that's not possible, then try to match the "look" of the missing plant in terms of texture, height, width, and bloom time (in that order). OTOH, it's a lot of fun to experiment within an existing design as well. Gardening should always be fun!